# Shortcut for a counts-per-time unit with siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx, units

I am writing first-aid related texts, where I have a lot of expressions like "/min" (like "she has an heart rate of 60/min") and so on.

I would like to write this kind of numbers with `siunitx` to get a nice rendering, but it expects to have a unit *before* the slash, or else it appends a one before it. To display a "60/min", I have to add a `\relax` in it. It works fine, but I'll have to write this many times and I'd like to shorten it.

Here is an example.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[range-units=single,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\permin}{\relax\per\minute}

\begin{document}

Heart rate 1: \qtyrange{60}{100}{\per\minute}.

Heart rate 2: \qtyrange{60}{100}{\relax\per\minute}.

% Heart rate 3: \qtyrange{60}{100}{\permin}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of the above example.]

It tried to create a "per minute" unit, but it still appends a one with just `\per\minute`, and if I add a `\relax` in `\DeclareSIUnit` it crashes. If I uncomment the third line in the above example, I get an error.

```tex
.../document.tex:15: Undefined control sequence.
\per ->\ERROR 

l.15 Heart rate 3: \qtyrange{60}{100}{\permin}

.../document.tex:15: Undefined control sequence.
\minute ->\ERROR 

l.15 Heart rate 3: \qtyrange{60}{100}{\permin}
```

It says "undefined control sequence", but when I try with `\DeclareSIUnit{\permin}{\per\minute}` (without `\relax`), it compiles without any error (but still appends a one before the `\per`).

So is there a way to create this kind of shortcut with siunitx, or do I have to use the second line expression? Or is there a cleaner way to do it?

PS: I know it should be "60 beats/min" or something equivalent, but I would like to use a shorter format for compact tabular data, which should be readable at a glance (for mementos).

I hope I'm not being too unclear...
Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that looks like a bug in the range code: I'd not allowed for suppressing the leading `1` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in the handling of repeated units](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/677). A fix will be on CTAN shortly, but you can patch with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-units = single, per-mode = symbol}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \siunitx_compound_quantity:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \bool_if:NT \l__siunitx_compound_unit_bracket_bool
        { \bool_set_true:N \l__siunitx_compound_exp_bracket_bool }
      \bool_if:NT \l__siunitx_compound_unit_repeat_bool
        { \bool_set_false:N \l__siunitx_compound_exp_combine_bool }
      \bool_lazy_or:nnT
        { \l__siunitx_compound_unit_bracket_bool }
        { ! \l__siunitx_compound_unit_repeat_bool }
        { \bool_set_false:N \l_siunitx_number_bracket_ambiguous_bool }
      \bool_set_true:N \l__siunitx_compound_unit_bool
      \__siunitx_compound_format:nn {#1} {#2}
      \bool_if:NF \l_siunitx_number_parse_bool
        { \siunitx_unit_format:nN {#2} \l__siunitx_compound_unit_tl }
      \str_if_eq:VnT \l_siunitx_quantity_prefix_mode_tl { combine-exponent }
        { \tl_clear:N \l__siunitx_compound_exp_tl }
      \bool_if:NTF \l__siunitx_compound_unit_repeat_bool
        { \__siunitx_compound_print:N \__siunitx_compound_print_quantity:x }
        {
          \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
            { \l__siunitx_compound_unit_bracket_bool }
            { \tl_if_empty_p:N \l__siunitx_compound_exp_tl }
            {
              \siunitx_print_number:V \l__siunitx_compound_bracket_open_tl
              \__siunitx_compound_print:N \siunitx_print_number:x
              \siunitx_print_number:V \l__siunitx_compound_bracket_close_tl
            }
            { \__siunitx_compound_print:N \siunitx_print_number:x }
          \__siunitx_compound_print_quantity:n { \c_empty_tl }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\qty{10}{\per\minute}
\qtyrange{60}{100}{\per\minute}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your quick answer! :)